# JSDoc @param as a predefined constant object

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Let's say I have a predefined constant object like this:

```
const person = {
   name: "",
   gender: "",
   age: 0
}
```

Then I have a function that requires the parameter must be the type of `person`:

```
/**
 * @param {*} personObj How can we enforce the personObj as the type of an existing constant object?
 */
function approve(personObj) {

}
```

How can I enforce the `personObj` to be the type of `person`? Is it possible to avoid using `@typedef`? Because I have many predefined constant objects of such that we do not want to rewrite all the definitions again. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with 2 different approaches:

1. Define the types in `jsdoc` comments as follows

```js
/**
 * @param { { name: string, gender: string, age: number } } personObj Person Object
 */
function approve(personObj) {
   // do stuff with personObj
}
```

All the popular Editors and IDE's will show the above-mentioned comments in a formatted way.

2. Write a `module.d.ts` file

You can also add a declaration file that defines all the type definitions used inside a module.

Create a `module.d.ts` file and declare your Module

```
// module.d.ts

export interface Person {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  age: number
}
```

Your code editor will use this declaration file to provide you with the hints and checks you need in your code.

More about declaration files [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)

Comment: Sorry, is this `type script`? I never use typescript before. If my node.js project has not been setup for typescript, can I still use approach #2? In `module.d.ts`, what is `d` stands for? Can it be anything?

Comment: Yes, this is typescript file, The purpose of declaration files is to introduce types in javascript code. `d` stands for declaration. you can name your file anything as `*.d.ts` where asterisk can be replaced by your module name. You need to use namespace declarations. You can follow the link I've added to look into ts docs

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
/**
 * @param {Object<name:string,gender:string,age:number>} personObj 
 */

function approve(personObj) {

}
```

Comment: Ya, I'm aware of this, but if I have many functions that make use of `Person` parameter, then I'll have to rewrite the definition as `@param` for all the functions. Any change of structure needs to change the JSDoc for all functions again...